# How to extend an ArrayInput to iterate on properties of an object

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have an API response like this:

```
{ ...
  "schedule":
  {
    "0": {"endTime": "15:00", "isHoliday": true,  "startTime": "14:00"}, 
    "1": {"endTime": "15:00", "isHoliday": false, "startTime": "14:00"}, 
    "2": {"endTime": "15:00", "isHoliday": true,  "startTime": "14:00"}, 
    "3": {"endTime": "15:00", "isHoliday": false, "startTime": "14:00"}, 
    "4": {"endTime": "15:00", "isHoliday": true,  "startTime": "14:00"}, 
    "5": {"endTime": "15:00", "isHoliday": true,  "startTime": "14:00"}, 
    "6": {"endTime": "15:00", "isHoliday": false, "startTime": "14:00"}
  }
}
```

I need an input that iterates over `schedule` properties. 
The closest one is an `ArrayInput` component which iterates over array elements, but not object keys.

Can someone give a clue on how to write it?

Answer (score 0):

Why not map the schedules:

```js
import { Edit, ArrayInput, SimpleFormIterator, BooleanInput, TextInput } from 'react-admin';

const PointEdit = props => {
  const schedule = Object.values(props.schedule)
  return (
    <Edit schedules={schedules}>
      <ArrayInput source="schedules">
        <SimpleFormIterator>
          <TextInput label="Start Time" source="startTime"/>
          <TextInput label="End Time" source="endTime"/>
          <BooleanInput label="Holiday" source="isHoliday" />
        </SimpleFormIterator>
      </ArrayInput>
    </Edit>
   )
}
```

Comment: Yes, looks like it's a right solution. Where do I put the mapping logic? My code looks like this:
```
const PointEdit = props => (
  <Edit {...props} >
    <ArrayInput source="schedules">
      <SimpleFormIterator>
        <TextInput label="Start Time" source="startTime"/>
        <TextInput label="End Time" source="endTime"/>
        <BooleanInput label="Holiday" source="isHoliday" />
      </SimpleFormIterator>
    </ArrayInput>
  </Edit>
);
```

Comment: @nextstopsun I've edited the answer. Hope it is answer to your question

Comment: Object.values(props.data.schedule) doesn't work because props doesnt have a `data` property.

Comment: @nextstopsun what are your props then?

Comment: It's a big object with `
basePath: "/points_admin"
hasCreate: false
hasEdit: true
hasList: true
hasShow: false
`
properties, but no `data` property.

Comment: @nextstopsun how do you store API response? in props / state ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199607/discussion-between-maciej-trojniarz-and-nextstopsun).